# How to Prevent Nmap , Displaying HTTP Header Details

Tags: iis-8, windows-server-2012, iis-8.5, nmap

I have 
OS: Windows Server 2012
IIS 8.0.

I Used MicroSoft's URLRewrite 2.1 For hiding HTTP Server Details.
Its working fine for Firebug(Firefox) , Developer Tool (IE).

But When i Fire Below Command in Nmap , It shows all Details related to that server.

Command : nmap -sV -p 443 172.16.40.45 172.16.4.45

Please Help.

Comment: If you want to hide the banner it must be done at server side.

Comment: Thanks OscarAkaElvis , Actually i Added URLRewrite2.1 , on that server's IIS , where my application is installed , but Still Nmap is capturing all Details Related to that server .

Comment: If you want to be helped by somebody put all the possible data. What nmap is showing, your expected result. Your URLRewrite modifications, etc. otherwise is impossible.

Comment: i downloaded 'URLRewrite2.1' From Microsoft Web Platform installer 5.0 . & in IIS for URLRewrite , i created Outbound Rules for Response_Server & Set its value to 'Private' . So it should not Show Banner Details (i want it should not show Server's Type & Version Details, it should show 'Private' which i set from URL Rewrite. ) . & i m testing this through Nmap , so when i fire command 'nmap -sV -p 8443 172.16.40.45' it should hide banner Details (Server's Type & Version ). Thanks ...